# Changing Collapsed navbar list background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm having this issue that when I collapse my navbar(and it becomes the toggle buttom) and I toggle the list on, the background color is transparent. Since I'm using a transparente background for the navbar, that should be expected, but I when the content is toggle-on, it overlaps with the text on the screen, and it becomes messy and ugly. I would like to set the background color of the div to change when i collapse to mobile version(bootstrap), is there any way to do that?

Here are my codes:

```css
.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  top: 60px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #4f82e9;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #4f82e9;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#offcanvas .navbar-nav > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent !important;
  border-radius: 2px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top js-navbar-top js-toggleClass">

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">ABA Arquitetura</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">

        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#lancamentos">Lançamentos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Serviços</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contato</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Add this to your CSS:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-collapse
    {
        background-color:#FA0;
    }
}
```

And a jsfiddle I used to come to this conclusion: https://jsfiddle.net/7gvg6mxp/

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this:
This works fine with bootstrap 4

```
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function () {
$("nav").toggleClass("bg-light");
})
```

your background could be transparent at first, but after clicking on the toggle button the background of navbar will be 'bg-light'.